# -server option for Launch4j?

Tags: java, launch4j

I've been poking around the launch4j website and can't seem to figure out how to set the `-server` program option, there's an [old forum post](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/forums/forum/332683/topic/1547000) indicating it might be a future option but no further details are available.

Is it possible to run the JVM in server mode using Launch4j?

Comment: For Oracle JVMs, -server is a default functionality.  The only way you can get a -client JVM is if  your running a 32bit JRE (not SDK).

Comment: @djangofan That is not true. It defaults to a server vm only on "server-class-machines", however this may be detected. On a 32bit Windows the default is client VM. All 64bit VMs are server VMs. See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_default

Comment: @timomeinen - In JDK 1.6, it was required to pass -server as the very FIRST option to the JVM.  Not sure if thats still true, but it might matter to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it within `<opt>` node for `<jre>` in [the configuration file](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html)

Answer (score 0):

or in `Maven` plugin configuration:

```
<jre>
    <minVersion>1.8.0_101</minVersion>
    <runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits>
    <opts>
        <opt>-server</opt>
    </opts>
</jre>
```